# AWS Crawler Throwing Connection Error When Glue Connection Test Passes

Tags: amazon-rds, aws-glue

I'm hitting an error on AWS and oogle has not been much help thus far.  Here is the problem I have.  I have setup a connection in Glue to my Oracle RDS.  When I test the connection it passes.  When I run the Crawler it fails with the following error:

```
ERROR : Error crawling database my_oracle_db:
SQLException:
SQLState: 08006
Error Code: 17002
Message: IO Error: Invalid connection string format, a valid format is: "host:port:sid"
```

I have manually altered the JDBC connection string so that the / between port and SID is replaced with :  I did test the connection both ways, and the test passed.  What could be causing the error to get thrown?

Comment: I am facing a similar issue with the following error. @william did you find any solution? SQLException:
SQLState: 08S01
Error Code: 0
Message: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.